# non-const pointer argument to a const double pointer parameter

Tags: c++, function, pointers, type-conversion, constants

The `const` modifier in C++ before star means that using this pointer the value pointed at cannot be changed, while the pointer itself can be made to point something else. In the below

```
void justloadme(const int **ptr)
{
    *ptr = new int[5];
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr = NULL;
    justloadme(&ptr);
}
```

`justloadme` function should not be allowed to edit the integer values (if any) pointed by the passed param, while it can edit the int* value (since the const is not after the first star), but still why do I get a compiler error in both GCC and VC++?

**GCC:** error: invalid conversion from `int**` to `const int**`

**VC++:** error C2664: 'justloadme' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int **' to 'const int **'. Conversion loses qualifiers

Why does it say that the conversion loses qualifiers? Isn't it gaining the `const` qualifier? Moreover, isn't it similar to `strlen(const char*)` where we pass a non-const `char*`

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As most times, the compiler is right and intuition wrong. The problem is that if that particular assignment was allowed you could break const-correctness in your program:

```
const int constant = 10;
int *modifier = 0;
const int ** const_breaker = &modifier; // [*] this is equivalent to your code

*const_breaker = & constant;   // no problem, const_breaker points to
                               // pointer to a constant integer, but...
                               // we are actually doing: modifer = &constant!!!
*modifier = 5;                 // ouch!! we are modifying a constant!!!
```

The line marked with [*] is the culprit for that violation, and is disallowed for that particular reason. The language allows adding const to the last level but not the first:

```
int * const * correct = &modifier; // ok, this does not break correctness of the code
```

Comment: Although it is agreeable that to disallow this `const` modifying fiasco the compiler does this. But using `int * const * correct` won't even allow me to do `*ptr = new int[5];`. What do I do?

Comment: The problem is most probably in that what you want to do is not what you are writting. What is it that you want to be done? The signature takes a `const int **` but you are passing an `int **` and treating it inside the function as a `int **`... do you really want that `const` in the signature?

Comment: Oh, now I get it! What I'm trying to do is conceptually wrong, so yes, you're right. Thanks!